# R Markdown: how to hide plots from being plotted inside RStudio?

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, rstudio

I have a R Markdown file in RStudio.

I have the following code:

````
```{r, fig.show="hide"}
plot(tree.boston)
text(tree.boston, pretty=0)
```
````

When I click on Run -> Run All (or Ctrl+Alt+R), the plot is included *inside RStudio*. That is, below the code, the plot appears.

How can I prevent the plot *inside RStudio*? I don't want plots below my code.

Comment: Where do you want it?

Comment: @Phil The plot? Nowhere. I want the code in the PDF output, and the plot nowhere, I don't want the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the preamble of your Rmd

```
editor_options:
    chunk_output_type: console
```

Answer (score 1):

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
plot(tree.boston)
text(tree.boston, pretty=0)
```
````

Should High the plot within Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

In `Preferences` / `R Markdown`, there is a checkbox:

> Show output inline for all R Markdown documents

Unselect it.

The plots will still be in the PDF output, but not inside the RStudio browser.

This answers the question you asked if I ignore the comments: how to get rid of the plots inside RStudio.  I wanted this too, which is why I answered it here.

In the comments you said you wanted to get rid of the plots everywhere, including the output PDF. In that case, @daniel-jachetta's answer is better.